# Jenkins & Java : How to specify input file location

Tags: java, jenkins

I have a java project which compares data in two excel files and displays the output. IN my eclipse project i created a folder data and in the code I wrote code read from root/data and it works fine as well. But my manager asked me to move this job to Jenkins. So my question is how do i specify the input folder path in Jenkins , Should it be the same server where Jenkins is installed or Jenkins can read data from another location in another server ?

Comment: (Jenkins has thousands of plugins; can do whatever you want.  If some thing is missing you can add new plugin.  )  Jenkins jobs can accept file parameters : Checkout https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Parameterized+Build

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default, Jenkins will work on the Job's workspace location, if you provide a path in the job (be it via Parameter or Env. variable etc), it will be relative to that location. 
However, you can specify an absolute path for anywhere on the Jenkins Server, which will also work.

If you wish to read data from another server, you will need to make it available to the job's runtime/access level.

One example would be to put this file on IIS or Network Share or other form of sharing, and download it during your chef job into the workspace.

Powershell example for downloading a file from IIS site:

```
    $source = "http://my-web-server-ip/download/mycsvfile.csv"
    $destination = "c:\my-jenkins-job-workspace\mycsvfile.csv"
    Invoke-WebRequest $source -OutFile $destination
```

Please consider the above is just a basic implementation of this, and this can be accomplish in a number of ways - which some may be better than others.

Comment: Thanks @freebourn . Can you please tell me one more way to dod this. I tried to copy using powershell but its not working in our corporate network. It says Powershell.exe is not present, and I dont have the authority to ask them to add powershell to jenkins.

Comment: Can you advise what plugins are available to you? Can you use bash? if yes you can try using wget :

                     wget -O $destination $source

Comment: freebourn : Finally i achieved this by adding File Parameter in Jenkins, so user can browse and provide input file from local and then Windows XCOPY to moved the files from workspace root folder to testdata folder. Thank a lot for your suggestions.